# 'localtime_s': is not a member of 'std' in VS2015

Tags: c++

The following C++ code does not compile with VS2015:

```cpp
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>

void main()
{
    const time_t t = std::time(nullptr);

    std::tm tm = {};

    std::localtime_s(&tm, &time);
}
```

The error messages are:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

t.cpp
t.cpp(10): error C2039: 'localtime_s': is not a member of 'std'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\ctime(17): 
note: see declaration of 'std'
t.cpp(10): error C2664: 'errno_t localtime_s(tm *const ,const time_t *const )': 
cannot convert argument 2 from 'time_t (__cdecl *)(time_t *const )' to 'const time_t *const '
t.cpp(10): note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

What can be a workaround?

Note: using `std::localtime()` is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [[headers]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/headers#10)

> Annex K of the C standard describes a large number of functions, with associated types and macros, which “promote safer, more secure programming” than many of the traditional C library functions. The names of the functions have a suffix of _­s; most of them provide the same service as the C library function with the unsuffixed name, but generally take an additional argument whose value is the size of the result array. If any C++ header is included, **it is implementation-defined whether any of these names is declared in the global namespace. (None of them is declared in namespace std.)**

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

and table 18 list `localtime_s` as a member so, because of the above section, we know that it is not defined in namespace `std` and if it does exist it will be in the global namespace.  Try using

```
::localtime_s(&tm, &time);
```

and if that still does not work it means your implementation does not support it.

Comment: global ::localtime_s(&tm, &time); compiles.